# jquery datatable search ajax only called on table load

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using Jquery datatables I have a custom ajax function 
"url": blah blah
"ajax": blah blah

It is called on the initial page load but it doesn't appear to be returned on searches although the search still works it appears to filter the data previously loaded, I might be wrong but I can't see anything happening in the console.

Is their another option I'm missing?

Comment: duh :- "serverSide": true,

Comment: is everything ok now ? else just post some code to figure it out

Comment: yeah I had deleted the serverside processing variable